# Regular expression is not working java.util.regex.*;

Tags: java, regex

I am having problems when I implement Regular Expressions in my code...

I'll give a quick explanation of it... I have a function that receives a String to check if that String contains an element of an `ArrayList` (these elements can be of one or more words). If it doesn’t contain any element of the list then it returns to write it to a file otherwise is ignored. First I did the following:

```
private boolean containDiscontinuedWord(String query) {
Matcher matcher;
Pattern pattern;
    for (String blackL : blackList) {
        pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b" + blackL + "\\b");
        matcher = pattern.matcher(query);
            while(matcher.find()) {
                return true;
            }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**The problem I have here is that when I run the application under a linux environment(jvm 1.5 installed) then nothing is written to the file... but it does under windows environment**. My application is built with 1.6 with 1.5 compatibility.

So I did the following:

```
private boolean containDiscontinuedWord(String query) {
    for (String blackL : blackList) {
        if(query.matches(".*\\b(" + blackL + ")\\b.*")){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And this function works just fine but without the "*" of my regular expression...but that I need to use for the exact match, but again it runs fine under windows environment. I have searched about this in so many ways but I just can't find something that fixes this problem, I don’t know if my regular expression is not correct or what can be... I hope you guys can give me a clue!

My apologies if this is a dumb question, but Thanks a lot for reading it!

Comment: Have you verified it's an issue in `containDiscontinuedWord` and not the bit that writes to the file?

Comment: Sounds like most probably you are looking at the wrong spot just like Dave Newton said.

Comment: Before using regex I was using contains(); but for example
String query = "This is my favorite laptop"; and in the ArrayList was a the element "favorite laptop" then it won’t work, but will if only be "favorite" or "laptop". with contains worked fine but only if there is only one word to find...

Answer (score 0):

You seriously need to investigate `indexOf`. The way you are building the regexp is already very error-prone (think about quoting). Plus, you did not understand the difference between "matching" and "searching" with regexps.

Comment: yeah I know indexOf() seems the only way out, but I can't just find any answer that helps why find() won’t work at all, thats why I adjusted match() function with the regular expression, but as I said it only work without *, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What are your black listed words? If they contain any regex meta-characters they will need to be quoted.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: no, they don't contain any regex meta-characters, the meta-characters are only present when i compile the pattern.they are a list of bad words and discontinue products.